# SQL select value from column when another column equals to given value

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a table called `payment`, which consists of the columns - `bill ID`, `group ID`, `u1`, `u1paid`, `u2`, `u2paid`, `u3`, `u3paid`, `u4`, `u4paid`, `u5`, `u5paid`. What I want to do is store the value of one of the paid columns **if my currently set userID is equal to the ID stored in one of the columns u1, u2...,etc in the row I have selected**.

Example, if the current **user ID** is equal to the ID stored in `u3`, I'd like to store the value of `u3paid` in a PHP variable. What is the SQL command to achieve this?

An attempt at a solution:

```
SELECT u1paid if u1 = SessionID or u2paid if u2 = SessionID or 
u3paid if u3 = SessionID or u4paid if u4 = SessionID or 
u5paid if u5 = SessionID FROM payment WHERE billID = BILLID;
```

I know that this isn't proper syntax, but it's the closest I can get to something SQL-like.

Second edit (on basis of twoleggedhorse's answer) :

```
$payment = "SELECT CASE WHEN u1 = '".$_SESSION['ID']."' THEN u1paid WHEN u2 = 
'".$_SESSION['ID']."' THEN u2paid WHEN u3 = '".$_SESSION['ID']."' THEN u3paid 
 WHEN u4 = '".$_SESSION['ID']."' THEN u4paid 
 WHEN u5 = '".$_SESSION['ID']."' THEN u5paid END AS PAID 
 FROM payment WHERE trackbill = '".$row['BID']."';"
```

After that, I'm trying to access the value from this statement by $payment['PAID'], but it still isn't working. Am I still messing something up in this?

Edit3 : The above command works, I just messed up one of the variable names :P

Comment: I've tried experimenting with a case statement, but I simply can't come up with anything concrete. This is small part of a larger assignment, and we haven't covered anything beyond simple Select and Update statements in SQL, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: well, this sounds like a pretty simple SELECT statement. Please edit your question with at least an attempt. I mean you can basically work this out just by talking it... You need to SELECT u3paid FROM the payment table, where u3 equals something... Don't get confused, just type out what you want in plain English and you'll see the query...

Comment: It seems that you believe your query will return just a single row. Is this the case? If so, why?

Comment: It should return a single row as billID = BILLID, and the billID's are unique.

Comment: OK - Have you read about SELECT statements? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp - start there... You seem to have not really done any research on your problem. This is very simple stuff. You just need to learn it. You are mixing some combination of PHP and SQL in a statement. PHP will use a connector to run SQL statements on the database - they aren't one and the same thing.

Comment: The connector file was provided to us by the tutor, so we just have to use the functions from that file to execute the SQL statements and get the result in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN u1 = SessionID THEN u1paid 
             WHEN u2 = SessionID THEN u2paid
             WHEN u3 = SessionID THEN u3paid
             WHEN u4 = SessionID THEN u4paid
             WHEN u5 = SessionID THEN u5paid
             ELSE 'No result found'
        END AS Paid
FROM    payment 
WHERE   billID = BILLID;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly after a few mishaps with the syntax, thank you!